# Install newtonsoft-json for .NET on Ubuntu

Tags: c#, .net, linux, ubuntu-16.04

I'm simply trying to parse some JSON that I'm getting back from an API call in C#. I'm using .NET on Ubuntu. To accomplish this, I've tried to install newtonsoft-json using

```
nuget install Newtonsoft.Json
```

The library installs successfully. Yet when I run the program, I get the following error:

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What is going on here? How do I get .NET to recognize the new library?

Also, I'm not particularly attached to this library, I just want to parse a frikin JSON string in .NET on Ubuntu. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out! I just had to manually alter my package.json file and then type `dotnet restore`. After that, newtonsoft-json worked just fine.

Comment: Could you explain please?
I don't see package.json file in my .NET Core Class Library solution.
Nor do I know where should I type "dotnet restore"
If I type it within command prompt of VS it tells me that:
Command "dotnet" is not valid.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command on terminal (This is OpenSUSE console/terminal. However, same concept apply for Ubuntu.).

```
xxxx@localhost:~/Path/To/Project>dotnet add package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Than

```
xxxx@localhost:~/Path/To/Project>dotnet restore
```

This should resolve it.

Answer (score -1):

This dll is available in Mono gac. you need to add a new reference or you get the error message. if you're using corefx then use dotnet restore. the package will be loaded.
 [check the link](https://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/vivid/universe/m/monodoc-newtonsoft-json-manual/install/index.html)

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install Newtonsoft.Json
```